# Script that moves files from a NAS to clients, executed on a server

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I got the following problem: at work, I have to code a script that copies the files from a NAS onto a few clients, using Remote PSSessions. The script is getting executed on a domain controller.

I think something is wrong with the remote session and the "copy the files" part. But I don't know what.

```cs
#SRC=Source Data to copy
$src1 = "\\NAS01\adm\sw\CAD\Dateien_fuer_SUPPORT_Verz\def_KOPA_Linie.lin"
$src2 = "\\NAS01\adm\sw\CAD\Dateien_fuer_SUPPORT_VerzSchlinie2.shx"
$src3 = "\\NAS01\adm\sw\CAD\Dateien_fuer_SUPPORT_Verz\Schlinie2.shp"

#PowerShell Check for AD-Service
Get-Service ad*
Get-Module

#Searching through AD for PC's called "WS"
$pc = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'name -like "WS" '

#New Powershell-Remotesession with the $pc
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $pc

#Check if the Directory exists, if it exists, copy the files inside
$Dir = "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2015\Support\"
if (Test-Path $Dir)
{
    Copy-Items -FromSession $session -Path $src1 + src2 + src3 -Destination "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2015\Support\"
}
else
{
    echo "tohuwabohu"
}
```

Comment: Does it output an error message? If so can you add it to your question.

Comment: PowerShell doesn't have a cmdlet `Copy-Items`, and `-Path $src1 + src2 + src3` is plain wrong syntax. Even if you made that syntactically correct (`-Path ($src1 + $src2 + $src3)`) it wouldn't do what you seem to expect (copy all 3 files), but concatenate all 3 path strings and give you an error because it can't find a file at that location. Change `-Path $src1 + src2 + src3` to `-Path $src1, $src2, $src3` and try again. Update your question with whatever error you're getting if it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, I'm currently in my apprenticeship and oly use PowerShell since like 2 weeks.

Comment: the pssession connection still doesnt work..

Comment: Edit your question and show your updated code. Also describe how *exactly* it "still doesn't work". Are you getting an error? What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

This will only bring back computers with the name WS:

```
$pc = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'name -like "WS" '
```

You need to use wild cards with -like
Example: if your computernames are "WS-1234-abc",WS-2345-afgt.
Use:

```
$pc = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'name -like "WS*"'
```

Your currentlly trying to open a remote session with no computer name

You need to run each Line of your script to see if you get the output you expect.

Copy-item (no s) does not require you to first open a remote session.
The path Parameter will take commas seperated values.
See help Copy-item

```
[-path] <string[]>
```

the [] tells use we can use comma seperated values
Example:

```
Copy-Item -Path $src1,$src2,$crs3 -Destination "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2015\Support\"
```